# Problem with installing headers in debian 9.5 stretch

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, header, debian, geoip

When I try to install header by using this command:
`apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

Then I get this output with error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.9.124-xxxx-std-ipv6-64
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.9.124-xxxx-std-ipv6-64'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.9.124-xxxx-std-ipv6-64'
```

I need those headers to install geoip, without them executing this command:
`modprobe xt_geoip`

Returns this error:

```
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.9.124-xxxx-std-ipv6-64/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module xt_geoip not found in directory /lib/modules/4.9.124-xxxx-std-ipv6-64
```

Here are my sources.list:
`https://pastebin.com/6eVpTuUD`

My debian version:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.5 (stretch)
Release:        9.5
Codename:       stretch
```

I want just to note that I am newbie in linux, sorry if this problem is obvious. I were trying to find answer on google but I did not manage to.

Comment: That's not a standard Debian kernel. I think it is for OVH. Do you have any extra repository sources listed in "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/"?

Comment: For get English output of commands just prefix their call with `LANGUAGE=en`. E.g. `LANGUAGE=en apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`. Such way you wouldn't need to translate your messages for others, and you will be sure that [no information will be lost](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough) during this translation.

Comment: Was the kernel image installed from a package? What does `dpkg-query -S /boot/vmlinux-4.9.124-xxxx-std-ipv6-64` output?

Comment: I am using OVH dedicated server. I have never updated kernel. I have commented ovh sources in `sources.list` because they all have time outs when trying do `apt update` (not iptables failure, they are clean).   
Here is output for "dpkg-query...":  
`dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /boot/vmlinux-4.9.124-xxxx-std-ipv6-64`

Comment: Here is my sources.list.d: ovhkernel.list. Content:  `https://pastebin.com/RvGzmZ8K`

Comment: I used LANGUAGE=en for `apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`. Output is in main post, I have edited it

Comment: Someone.. Something :(?